# How create revesre proxy that can serve more than one site based on HOST header in twisted?

Tags: python, python-2.7, twisted

I have code like this  for a reverse proxy server

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.web import proxy, server

site = server.Site(proxy.ReverseProxyResource('www.yahoo.com', 80, ''))
reactor.listenTCP(8080, site)
reactor.run()
```

Its working fine. I want serve more than one site instead of just "yahoo.com".
I mean if request host header is yahoo, then return yahoo.com . if request header is google , then return google.com . How can i achieve this ?

Comment: add list of sites, then for site in sites reactor.listenTCP should work, but I'm not sure enough to post it as an answer :)